# Autogenerate summaries based on pre-existing topics?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, information-extraction

I'd like to do the following given a document:

- create a summary using pre-existing topics

In the first scenario, documents are neatly organized in a uniform way. 
For example, most Wikipedia movie articles have the following subtopics (ex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Us_(2012_film))

- Plot
- Cast
- Reception
- other optional topics

In the second scenario, documents contain the same info as above; however,  documents do NOT have clean organization. Documents may use the same or similar language but organized differently.

In both cases, given the subtopics, I'd like to extract this info from a document.

Are there any machine learning/natural language processing strategies/algorithms that I can use? Combination of algorithms is fine. Algorithms that mostly work are also fine.

Update: It looks like what I want is *Information Extraction*.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to go about this is to assign those topics to the sentences in each section [1]. As it seems that you have annotated data, you can train a "sentence topic/section model" with that. According to [1], even a multinomial naïve Bayes classifier does the job already pretty well.

As to the summarization aspect, unless you have training data, I would look into *extractive* summarization techniques [2] - that is, selecting the best sentences from the existing ones for the summary. The work of [2], LexRank, has a few implementations in the wild you can use. If you have summaries to learn from, you can look into *abstractive* techniques that generate new sentences from the existing ones [3], too. If you check [4], [3] has some sample implementations floating around.

[1] http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/25/23/3174.full

[2] http://jair.org/papers/paper1523.html

[3] http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00685

[4] http://gitxiv.com/

Comment: interesting worth looking into. But are these algs used in production i.e., in the wild? Concerned they may not be robust enough

Comment: Took a look at [1]. Some of the issues: (a) manual sentence annotation, (b) not clear how well it generalizes to other domains. I imagine that [1] works because bio-medical articles are mostly written the same. The pro is that it uses a relatively simple method that should be easy to validate.

Comment: Took a look at LexRank. Unfortunately, "the goal is to produce a
summary of multiple documents about the same topic." I'm trying to produce a summary of a single document.

Comment: I am not aware of a technique that generalizes across domains, so building a domain model is probably your best hope and you might to just have to "bite the supervised bullet", but I would be happy to be proven wrong. As to extractive summarization techniques, they can be applied to single documents (assuming the documents are sufficiently long to determine the most "salient" sentences in the first place...). As to how used these techniques are in the wild: They got their inventors hired by Google and Facebook... :-)

Comment: [3] seems to be for "headline generation". It's fairly advanced though and worth investigating.

Comment: Note that technique is supervised - it learns to summarize articles to the headlines (the "label"). That is why I assumed extractive techniques are both more feasible and appropriate regarding the problem you described - summarizing subsections of movie reviews (because you'd have no such training data).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I can think of is to pose this as a sequence classification problem where the classes are the sub-topics . Given a sentence (or maybe a paragraph) the classifier outputs the sub-topic probability. Training a LSTM classifier should be possible as you have a lot of labeled data (sentences,sub-topics)

The problem with this approach may be that the final out-put is non-coherent. Using paragraphs can help,or maybe conditioning on the previous classification probabilities.